# how can I make JQuery Owl Carousel larger on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I want to properly change the Mobile dimensions (height) when my websites opens in a mobile device.

As you can see in the photo attached, the gallery height is too small and I want to make it a little bit bigger for best viewing while in mobile, while preserving a responsive dimensions in all screen sizes the other mobile devices.

For some reason, I couldn't managed to do it properly. I'll be glad to have your help!

[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

We'll be much helpful to you if you provide some code example.

Just looking at the photo, have you tried either removing the padding on both sides, or add a negative margin on both sides to pull it to the edges.